# Which editor was emacs written in?

Tags: emacs, history

When [RMS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Stallman) first wrote GNU emacs, which editor did he use?

Comment: The original EMACS was written in 1976 by Carl Mikkelsen, David A. Moon and Guy L. Steele Jr. as a set of Editor MACroS for the TECO editor. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He used a hacked version of TECO for the first version of Emacs. And he probably used some existing version of Emacs to write GNU Emacs.

The MIT AI Lab (where Richard Stallman was working at that time) was using the TECO editor, which was a cause of some frustrations for its users. He saw some great features on the "E" Editor at the Standford AI Labs. So, he decided to implement some of those features on TECO with macros.

The enhancements were great but the result soon became a hell of macros with multiple issues from one terminal to another. Then, he (with Guy Steele) refactored all of those in a new software: Emacs was born.

Many forks were developed by many hackers, one the most popular (and the first one to run on Unix) being Gosling Emacs in the early 1980s. As Gosling Emacs was proprietary, RMS wrote an enhanced and free version of it: GNU Emacs.

Comment: Stallman started work on GNU Emacs in 1984 which was almost 10 years after he started work on E. It is much more likely that he used an earlier version of emacs until he could use GNU emacs itself as an editor. The Wikipedia article that @choroba mentions in the comment above contains a brief history of what happened between E and GNU emacs.

Comment: AFAIK GNU Emacs was not started in order to "free" Gosling Emacs.  Instead, Richard started GNU Emacs by modifying Gosling Emacs (which was not clearly proprietary at that point anyway) to have a real Lisp underneath:  Gosling Emacs was designed with a Lisp-ish (parens everywhere, but no real Lisp data-structures like cons cells) *extension* language, whereas Richard wanted a real Lisp *implementation* language.  AFAIK he ended up having to rewrite the rest of Gosling Emacs's C code later on when Gosling sold his code to Unipress who then threatened Richard.

Comment: You're right @Stefan : Gosling Emacs was free at the beginning. But UniPress began selling Gosling Emacs in 1983 and RMS started to work on GNU Emacs in 1984.

Comment: This area is indeed not as clear as I made it out to be: I've seen conflicting elements and haven't yet managed to clarify the exact ordering of the various events: "Richard gets access to Gosling Emacs's code", "Richard starts modifying Gosling Emacs", "Gosling sells his code to Unipress", "Unipress asks Richard to stop".  Any pointers to "evidence" would be very welcome.

Comment: The timeline given by RMS is in this speech: https://www.gnu.org/gnu/rms-lisp.en.html

Comment: Here's another good source for early Emacs history, by Bernard Greenberg: https://www.multicians.org/mepap.html